# Flood fill algorithm memory leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, unity-game-engine, paint, flood-fill

I've got a memory leak somewhere. I've searched it over so many times, and it looks solid to me. I just.. can't... find it...
Ok, background. This is a stack driven flood fill, and this bit of code is the only spot where I add something to the stack. There is more code, so if no one can find a memory leak, I'll post some more of it.

Here's the strangest part about this. The code works fine with just one color + line art (pictexture), but when using more than one color and using the fill bucket, I get those weird memory leaks.

```
 //descend to the floor
            while(true)
            {

                if(++iterator > total)
                {
                    Debug.Log("broke in the stupid down loop...");
                    break;
                }

                //if we hit line art or a color we're not changing, break out of the loop
                if(PicTexture.GetPixel((int)coords.x, (int)coords.y).a > .5f ||
                   MyTexture.GetPixel((int)coords.x, (int)coords.y) != ColorToChange || coords.y < 0)
                {
                    break;
                }


                //if we're looking right and find an open spot in our texture
                if(reach.right && MyTexture.GetPixel((int)coords.x + 1, (int)coords.y) == ColorToChange
                   && PicTexture.GetPixel((int)coords.x + 1, (int)coords.y).a < .5f)
                {
                    reach.right = false;    //search it and stop looking right
                    if(!search.Contains(new Vector2((int)coords.x + 1, (int)coords.y)))
                        search.Push(new Vector2((int)coords.x + 1, (int)coords.y));
                }
                else
                {
                    if(MyTexture.GetPixel((int)coords.x + 1, (int)coords.y) != ColorToChange
                       || PicTexture.GetPixel((int)coords.x + 1, (int)coords.y).a >= .5f)   //if theres a wall and we're not looking right
                        reach.right = true; //look for an opening to the rightq
                }

                //same thing for left
                if(reach.left && MyTexture.GetPixel((int)coords.x - 1, (int)coords.y) == ColorToChange
                   && PicTexture.GetPixel((int)coords.x - 1, (int)coords.y).a < .5f)
                {
                    reach.left = false;
                    if(!search.Contains(new Vector2((int)coords.x - 1, (int)coords.y)))
                        search.Push(new Vector2((int)coords.x - 1, (int)coords.y));
                }
                else
                {
                    if(MyTexture.GetPixel((int)coords.x - 1, (int)coords.y) != ColorToChange
                       || PicTexture.GetPixel((int)coords.x - 1, (int)coords.y).a >= .5f)
                        reach.left = true;
                }

                MyTexture.SetPixel((int)coords.x, (int)coords.y, BrushColor);
                coords.y--;
            }
```

edit: I just realized I forgot to mention the weirdest part. This code works just fine until I use colors other than the starting color (blue). Once I change colors, even if it's back to blue, it still breaks.

Comment: How do you know that you have a memory leak? What are the symptoms you experience? What debugging tools have you used to try to identify the source of the leak? What did they show?

Comment: I've been using Unity's Debug.Log() to throw debug statements in to see how big the search stack is, and that iterator to break me out of the loop if it gets stuck. When I use just one color, the stack size never surpasses 75, and the iterator maintains a reasonable count. I've been breaking the loop at 600,000 iterations and at a stack size of 100 in order to not crash the program.

Comment: I don't think this is a memory-leak but a problem with your algorithm

Comment: Nah, the algorithm was fine, there was an issue with how I was receiving my colors. The person who wrote the color picker code had used a different color format than me, so it would run into colors that it wasn't quite sure what to do with and would basically just continually add searches to the stack.

Answer (score 2):

First, use a profiler.  I have had pleasant experiences with [RedGate's ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/).  It is really the quickest way to get the information you need when the problem isn't obvious.

As for your code, all I noticed at first glance is that you may be creating a large number of `Vector2` objects in a very short amount of time.  I have no idea if this is actually causing the problem you are seeing though.

As an aside, GDI+ is slow as a dog. If you begin to notice poor performance you may want to consider using `Bitmap.LockBits` to get a pointer to the image data in memory and operate on that.  In my experience GDI+ is simply not suitable for manipulations on images of even modest size.

Comment: My dog is quite fast, but then I've mostly used GDI+ for vector graphics, not for bitmaps. +1 for RedGate.

Comment: Thanks man, although I'm using Unity's texture2d, and they don't have a native Bitmap.LockBits function built into it.
Here's the weird thing. This code works just fine when I start it up. It's not until I change colors and try to use the flood fill that it start's misbehaving. Color shouldn't matter though, since it's only ever looking for the replacement color.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out it wasn't entirely my fault. The guy who wrote the color picker code was using a different color format than me, but the engine that we're using sometimes will implicitly convert one format to another, which is why it still worked sometimes. Very very strange. 
Thanks for your help though guys!